# How to run RSA software fob on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, rsa

I am using RSA software fob on windows. I want to use software fob on ubuntu. I didnot find any relevant software on RSA website for using software fob on ubuntu. I tried to use RSA firefox plugin but even that does not work properly. With firefox plugin I am not able to add my id file. The button doesnot work with my firefox version 3.6.3. 
Has anybody used RSA software fob on ubuntu? I have heard that it works with J2ME simulator but I dont want to use it for just for RSA.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like RSA offers an 'Authentication Agent' on their [download page](http://www.rsa.com/node.aspx?id=1081).  It's probably just a PAM module that you'll have to install; they should have details and instructions.